# Approach to build non restful form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have rails application which represent multistep investigation form.

Urls look like `research/step1`, `research/step2`, `research/step3` etc.

At one of this step (3/10) - I have form of user settings (email, phone, name etc).

How to organize controllers with actions to processing user data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you want to build a multistep form (also known as a "wizard").

Here is an episode from RailsCasts that goes over this topic that you might find helpul: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms.